# Get value of "name" in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
Category = collection.find({},{ name: true }).toArray();
console.log("Categories Found", Category);
```

**Output:**

```
Promise { [ 
            { name: 'Agriculture' },
            { name: 'engineer' } 
        ] }
```

How do I get the value of **name**?
(NOTE: Working in node JS)

Comment: `collection.find({},{ name: true }).toArray().then(function(data){ console.log("Categories Found", data); })`

Comment: Another approach would be to use the [**`distinct()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#distinct) method which will give you the names in an array with a single call, as in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41285487/122005).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toArray` is an asynchronous function that returns a promise. You can get your categories in one of two ways:

Promise style:

```
collection.find({},{ name: true }).toArray()
    .then(categories => {
        console.log(categories);
    });
```

Callback style:

```
collection.find({},{ name: true }).toArray((err, categories) => {
    console.log(categories);
});
```

Of course, it is a good practice to have some error handling: add `.catch` to the promise chain, or check if `err` is truthy in the callback.

Answer (score 3):

Since you get back a promise, you can use `.then()` to get to the result, and then get to your data with a loop :)

```
collection
    .find({}, { name: true })
    .toArray()
    .then(function(result) { 

        result.forEach(function(data) {

            console.log("name: %s", data.name); 

        });

    });
```

Have fun :)

Comment: how do i add these names into an array. for ex: 
cat = ["name1","name2"]

Comment: OK I see :) you need to learn a bit more about NodeJS or rather on the new features of JavaScript. In essence you have to put your code inside the `.then()` and keep on nesting until you reach the end of what you want to do. This is called the *Callback Hell* (http://callbackhell.com). The name is not that nice, but this is the coding style of JavaScript. You can avoid this type of style, but that would require a lot of explanation. I give you lots of good keywords for uncle Google. You should be able to take it from hear :)

Comment: Thanks. Though I thought if there was something more optimised :)

Comment: Not sure how do you understand the word *optimised* but this doesn't mean is a slow approach or anything, it is just a different approach. Google also another thing *NodeJS Event Loop*. You'll learn why dis approach in NodeJS is the right one, and how you an make your app work very slowly if you don't understand why this is. In the last 6 months a toon of good article showed up, that will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values in an array you can use the **[`distinct()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#distinct)** method as follows:

```
collection.distinct("name").then(function(categories) { 
    console.log("Categories Found", categories); 
    console.log("First Category", categories[0]); 
})
```

or using a callback function as:

```
collection.distinct("name", function(err, categories) { 
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Categories Found", categories); 
    console.log("First Category", categories[0]); 
})
```